# React dev tools not working: "Error in event handling for (unknown)"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, reactjs

I downloaded the React dev tools chrome extension, but they aren't loading on my React app. I am getting a weird exception from the console that I could not find by googling. Here is a screenshot of the exception.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you edit the question and add the relevant code (include.preload.js)? Also the error says favicon.ico isn't found, so what happens if you add the favicon to your local webserver?

Comment: @wOxxOm that is not my code, it appears to be the code of the extension. The React app itself is functioning fine. Also favicon shouldn't matter.

Comment: Oh, googling the extension id produces... [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb)! What happens if you disable it (and start using uBlock :-)?

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks man! will do :)

Comment: @wOxxOm it is still not working :( I removed ABP and added uBlock origin, now they don't show up and there is no error message. I restarted chrome as well

Comment: React dev tools issue tracker is [this way](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook recently updated the react dev tools and they are now working for me.

Comment: Still broken here. Uninstalled and reinstalled, restarted chrome. No dice. 

It is worth noting that there is an issue with webpack-dev-server not exposing React as a global. An npm module expose-loader is supposed to fix this with the line  `require('expose?React!react');`  but this still does not fix the issue for me.

Source: http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2014/08/31/configure-reactjs-with-webpack-and-grunt/

Answer (score 1):

Settings > Extensions > React Developer Tools > Allow access to file URLs

Comment: Actually, this may not be a solution since your serving from `localhost:8080`.

Comment: That didn't work either. At this point I have literally disabled all my other extensions and the tools are still showing blank.

Comment: Yer sorry, I jumped in too early as it's a solution to a common problem. I advise hitting the [react dev tools issue tracker](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues) too.